# How to get the text out from a dynamically added textbox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I am now making a word writer one that will write a word file out of what there is typed into my program. It works just fine buuut. When I am adding some textboxes to my table they get a seprate name but how to I choose one of them and get the text field out of it when I click on save?

Here is my table filler

```
private void filltabel()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= ddlServer.SelectedIndex; i++)
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = "<h3>Server " + i + "</h3>";
            TableRow trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            tCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
            tCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Servernavn: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtServerServernavn" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            //trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Rolle: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtServerRolle" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "IP: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtServerIP" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            //trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Administrator: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtServerAdministrator" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "PW: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtServerPW" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            //trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "HW model: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtServerHWModel" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "S/N: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtServerSN" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            //trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Garenti: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtServerGaranti" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Kommentar: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtServerKommentar" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= ddlPrinter.SelectedIndex; i++)
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = "<h3>Printer " + i + "</h3>";
            TableRow trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            tCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
            tCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "HW Model: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtPrinterHWModel" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            //trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "IP: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtPrinterIP" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            trow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(trow);
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Kommentar: ";
            tCell.Controls.Add(label);
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "txtPrinterKommentar" + i;
            textbox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            tCell = new TableCell();
            trow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            tCell.Controls.Add(textbox);
        }
    }
```

so basicly for my first textbox it will be "txtServerServernavn" + i where the i == 0.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < antalserver; i++)
        {
            TextBox test = Request.Params["txtServerServernavn" + i];
            serverArr[i, 0] = test.Text;
        }
```

right now the request.params is something I tried but hope you will understand it :)
basicly that is where I think my problem is so what do I have to put in there instead to read it?

**EDIT**
Okay think there was some need of more information here. I got 2 dropdown boxes in my program that both will add some more table cells and rows to my table1.
right now when I change the ddl it will do a postback changing how many visable textboxes there should be. and when I then click on save I want it to be sent to a docx but it allways just returns null.
[image: This picture shows 1 server and nothing else]
-------------------------spacer---------------------------------------------------------------
[image: this shows 1 server and 4 prints]

Comment: Note that you have to recreate all of your dynamic  controls on every postback with the same ID's as before. Then you can use `Table1.FindControl("txtServerServernavn" + i);` to get the reference in `Page_Load` or later.

Comment: so basicly its just             
if (IsPostBack)
            {
                filltabel();
            } ? and then use your cammand ok I try it :)

Comment: Normally you would create and re-create dynamic controls in `Page_Init`, so you don't lose their content during PostBack.

Comment: No, it's `filltabel()` (always) But don't overwrite the `Text` which you want the user to change.

Comment: yeah not sure I totally understand it donno about that page_init you talked about might take a look at that also.
but I stopped the filltabel() from my ddlchanges into page load if postback so that it wont create 2 of the same ID's but still TextBox test = (TextBox)Table1.FindControl("txtServerServernavn" + i); returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay since I could not get any help with this problem I decided to use an alternative way of doing it.

I am hardcoding it all now in my Dokumentation.aspx in difrent tables for less code in the codebehind. I could just hide alle the lable and textboxes but that would require alot more code in my codebehind.

in my codebehind I am just running this for the server list.

```
        Table[] T = new Table[] { Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, Table6, Table7, Table8, Table9, Table10 };
        foreach (Table t in T)
        {
            t.Visible = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ddlServer.SelectedIndex; i++)
        {
            T[i].Visible = true;
        }
```

this also gives me the result I was looking for but now I can get into my table without any trouble at all